# Black Hole Requests for Curl Post from Seperate server CakePHP

Tags: apache, security, cakephp, post, curl

Im trying to create a URL location where another service can send json POST data with the cURL library. Im getting 400 apache errors and Getting:

```
**Security Error**
The requested address was not found on this server.

 Request blackholed due to "auth" violation.
```

In the CakePHP app have tried disabling the security component and setting the correct route in the router but that does not seem to help.

Here is my controller action, my model beforeFind and the route:

```
public function hello() {
    $data = $this->request->data;
    CakeLog::write('helloSignResponse', $data);
    if ($data) {
        $this->Security->validatePost = false;
        CakeLog::write('helloSignResponse', $data);
        if ($this->request->data['signature_request']['is_complete'] == true) {
            $signature = $this->request->data['signature_request']["signature_request_id"];
            $agent = $this->Agent->findBySignature('first', array('conditions' => $data['id'], 'feilds' => array('id')));
            $this->Agent->id = $agent['Agent']['id'];
            $this->User->id = $data['Agent']['user_id'];
            if (!( $this->Agent->saveFeild('status', 1) && $this->User->saveFeild('status', 1))) {
                CakeLog::write('helloSign', 'Did Not update the user status and agent status');
            }
        }
        return 'Hello API Event Received.';
    }
}

//Model

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('hello');
    if ($this->action == 'hello') {
        $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
        $this->Security->validatePost = false;
    }
}

//route
 Router::connect('/hello', array('plugin' => 'PhoneKarma', 'controller' => 'Agents', 'action' => 'hello'));
```

What else am I supposed to do in  CakePHP to prevent this or accept POST data from a different server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the beforeFilter must be within the controller not the model for these functions to work. Here is the working beforeFilter:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('hello');
    $this->Auth->allow('hello');
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Comment: that is because `beforeFilter` is a controller method, not a model method.